# Using MP3 ID3 decoder with PHP Package

Tags: php, mp3, id3

So I'm working on a site right now that dynamically builds a playlist of all the .mp3 files in a directory on my server.  It works great but I realized there is a bug in grabbing the title of the song. For some reason it only allows for a 30 character limit when it pulls a tag. So if I have a song named "Really Long Song That Has More Than 30 Characters" it only returns "Really Long Song That Has More".

I'm using this http://pear.php.net/package/MP3_Id/redirected package to read the tags and looked at the source .php file but was unable to decipher what needed to be updated to pull more than 30 characters.

I was hoping that someone had more experience with this package or PHP ID3 tags in general and could either help me modify the source for the package I'm using now or to suggest a newer package accomplishing the same thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at MP3_Id, it seems that it only supports IDv1, and your MP3 file could be IDv2.

Have a look at [getID3()](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/), which has support for various types of MP3 files and a few other nice features.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Looking into it now and it does definitely look better than MP3_Id :D Thanks again.